# How can i create a windows vagrant box from existing windows iso image

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows, vagrant-plugin

I have iso image of windows 7. How can i create windows vagrant box using this iso image.

```
I tried "vagrant box add name fileLocation of iso". But box wasn't created.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Vagrant works with box not OS ISO**

You can read more on box at https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes.html but basically Boxes are the package format for Vagrant environments. A box can be used by anyone on any platform that Vagrant supports to bring up an identical working environment.

The easiest to start with is to download an existing box (`.box` file) both https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search and http://www.vagrantbox.es are good resources to find a box that should match your need.

If really you want to start with the ISO and build your own box (*this is more advanced topic*, I would only recommend for specific usage), you would need to look at the `packer` tool (https://www.packer.io) and getting existing templates for your target OS (like https://github.com/joefitzgerald/packer-windows for windows box)